# Log4net - object reference not set issue

Tags: c#, iis, log4net

I have 2 test and 1 production server.

In my global.asax file - I have this one line of code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    Logging.ConfigureLogging();
}
```

On both test servers its working fine, but on the production server, its generating an object reference not set exception. Any ideas on what in the production environment could be causing this error?

Comment: You'd better post full stacktrace.

Comment: What is your configuration file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "highly skilled support guys" installed it to a virtual directory of MOSS...
Guys - nothing co-exists with sharepoint...